# Connect to IBM DB2 using Korean characters from JDBC

Tags: utf-8, db2

I have a IBM DB2 10.1 Express edition installed with codeset UTF-8, and codepage 1208. I am able to create Tables and columns with korean characters.

But when i create a korean user and try to log in using that, It gives me a error " Unable to convert unicode string to ebcdic format". I tried using db2jcc and db2jcc4.jar, Also i tried from DB2 CLP .

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "create a korean user"?  What operating system / version are you running DB2 on?

Comment: It means, I have created user with korean characters, I am using windows7 and DB2 is running in windows 7. I have created user name with korean characters in windows and used the same to login. Also I have created a user in english and successfully i am able to login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 supports [only single-byte characters in authorization names](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001029.html).  If the character you're using in the ID is a multibyte character then I believe DB2 will not be able to authenticate it.